# How to change TinyMCE 4 image inline toolbar

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4, rich-text-editor

[image: Tinymce]

When we highlight the image, the inline toolbar will be shown, how to change these buttons?

It should be changeable right? Because Wordpress also using TinyMCE

[image: tinymce in wordpress]

Here's the Wordpress rich editor

I searched for long time and couldn't find any documentation about this.

Any idea how to change or remove the buttons?

P/S: I'm using tinymce v4.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has done a fair bit of customization to TinyMCE so don't assume that because you see something in WordPress its part of TinyMCE's open source solution.  You do have the ability to modify what is visible on the toolbar for the Image Tools plugin as documented here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/imagetools/#imagetools_toolbar

For example:

```
imagetools_toolbar: 'editimage imageoptions | alignleft aligncenter alignright',
```

...this adds the alignment options to the toolbar.